# Pythonic way to broadcast/loop through values when expanding kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function `foo` which has a lot of keyword arguments:

```
def foo(blah=1, blih='abc', blohp=('improbable', 'towel', 42)):
    pass
```

I have a function `bar` which calls function `foo` in a loop, and expands `kwargs`:

```
def bar(n, **kwargs):
    for i in range(n):
        foo(**kwargs)
```

I have three equally important use cases:

1. Broadcasting: `kwargs` is a standard `dict` and `bar` expands it for every call to `foo` (`foo` always gets called with the same keyword arguments). This is what's implemented above.
2. Loop: all the values in `kwargs` are wrapped in some kind of iterable (with length `n`) and `bar` expands each new value in the iterable for each new call to `foo` (`foo` gets called with different keyword arguments each time).
3. Combination: some values in `kwargs` are wrapped in some kind of iterable, to be handled similar to `2.` while some are not, to be broadcasted similar to `1.`.

Note the actual keyword arguments received by `foo` are arbitrary (so they may actually be an iterable object themselves - like `blih` and `blohp`).

What's a concise, pythonic pattern to implement this kind of behaviour and simultaneously satisfy all use cases?

Comment: Is `'abc'` one value or three?

Comment: One, forgot to add it as an example of an iterable object that `foo` receives normally. Edited the question to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it assuming that you wanted to call `bar` twice when `n==2` and all `kwargs` are iterables:

```
from collections import abc
from itertools import repeat

def foo(blah=1, blih='abc', blohp=('improbable', 'towel', 42)):
    print(blah, blih, blohp)

def bar(n, **kwargs):
    args = []
    for v in kwargs.values():
        # Turn single argument to iterable, treat strings as single arg
        if isinstance(v, str) or not isinstance(v, abc.Iterable):
            v = repeat(v)

        args.append(v)

    # Iterable that returns a tuple containing one item from each of the
    # iterables created above
    args = zip(*args)
    for i in range(n):
        foo(**dict(zip(kwargs, next(args))))

d = {
    'blah': 1,
    'blih': ['abc', 'def'],
    'blohp': [
        ('improbable', 'towel', 42),
        ('improbable', 'towel', 43)
    ]
}

bar(2, **d)
bar(2, blah='blah', blih='blih', blohp='blohp')
```

Output:

```
1 abc ('improbable', 'towel', 42)
1 def ('improbable', 'towel', 43)
blah blih blohp
blah blih blohp
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's exactly what you asked for:

```
from itertools import product, combinations
from operator import itemgetter


def wrap_as_iterable(val):
    """Make sure a value is always a list or tuple."""
    if isinstance(val, (tuple, list)):
        return val
    else:
        return (val, )


def foo(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)  # Just printing the arguments


def bar(**kwargs):
    # Wrap each keyword argument as iterable
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        kwargs[key] = wrap_as_iterable(value)

    # Loop through all combinations of the keyword-value combinations, that's
    # just the broadcasting case, no repeats. However repeats would be easy to
    # implement with the "range" you already have.
    for valuecomb in product(*kwargs.values()):
        foo(**dict(zip(kwargs, valuecomb)))
```

Just to show some sample cases:

```
>>> bar(blah=1, blih='abc', blohp=('improbable', 'towel', 42))
{'blih': 'abc', 'blah': 1, 'blohp': 'improbable'}
{'blih': 'abc', 'blah': 1, 'blohp': 'towel'}
{'blih': 'abc', 'blah': 1, 'blohp': 42}

>>> bar(blah=(1,2,3), blih=('abc', 'def'), blohp=('improbable', 'towel', 42))
{'blih': 'abc', 'blah': 1, 'blohp': 'improbable'}
{'blih': 'abc', 'blah': 1, 'blohp': 'towel'}
{'blih': 'abc', 'blah': 1, 'blohp': 42}
{'blih': 'abc', 'blah': 2, 'blohp': 'improbable'}
{'blih': 'abc', 'blah': 2, 'blohp': 'towel'}
{'blih': 'abc', 'blah': 2, 'blohp': 42}
{'blih': 'abc', 'blah': 3, 'blohp': 'improbable'}
{'blih': 'abc', 'blah': 3, 'blohp': 'towel'}
{'blih': 'abc', 'blah': 3, 'blohp': 42}
{'blih': 'def', 'blah': 1, 'blohp': 'improbable'}
{'blih': 'def', 'blah': 1, 'blohp': 'towel'}
{'blih': 'def', 'blah': 1, 'blohp': 42}
{'blih': 'def', 'blah': 2, 'blohp': 'improbable'}
{'blih': 'def', 'blah': 2, 'blohp': 'towel'}
{'blih': 'def', 'blah': 2, 'blohp': 42}
{'blih': 'def', 'blah': 3, 'blohp': 'improbable'}
{'blih': 'def', 'blah': 3, 'blohp': 'towel'}
{'blih': 'def', 'blah': 3, 'blohp': 42}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up `bar` so that you can tell it what you want to broadcast:

```
def bar(iter_kwargs, broadcast_kwargs):
    for iter_kwarg in iter_kwargs:
        foo(**dict(broadcast_kwargs, **iter_kwarg))
```